# How to record high quality video using webRTC mediaRecorder

Tags: google-chrome, webrtc, puppeteer, chromium, mediarecorder

I'm using following code to record screen of chrome browser. By defaul the output video is in vp9 profile-0. I need better color depth. So **I want to use profile-2**. Any idea how to specify that.

```
                chrome.desktopCapture.chooseDesktopMedia(['tab', 'audio'], streamId => {
                    navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia({
                        audio: true,
                        video: {
                            cursor: 'never',
                            frameRate: 60,
                            //aspectRatio: 0.8,
                            displaySurface: 'browser'
                        }
                    })
                    .then(function(stream) {
                        var chunks=[];
                        recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, {
                            videoBitsPerSecond: 5000000,
                            ignoreMutedMedia: true,
                            mimeType: 'video/webm; codecs=vp9',
                        });
                        recorder.ondataavailable = function (event) {
                            console.log("bg recorder data available");
                            if (event.data.size > 0) {
                                chunks.push(event.data);
                            }
                        };
                        recorder.onstop = function () {
                            console.log("bg recorder stop");
                            var superBuffer = new Blob(chunks, {
                                type: 'video/webm'
                            });

                            var url = URL.createObjectURL(superBuffer);

                            chrome.downloads.download({
                                url: url,
                                filename: filename
                            }, ()=>{
                            });
                        }

                        recorder.start();
                    }, error => console.log('Unable to get user media', error))
                })`enter code here`
```